ExcelJS изменение стиля ячейки
пытаюсь через ExcelJS сделать цвет заливки ячейки на красный, но цвет расползается на всю строку

const Excel = require('exceljs');
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx
 .readFile(fileName)
 .then((e) => {
   const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Лист1');
   const red = {
    type: 'pattern',
    pattern: 'solid',
    fgColor: { argb: 'FFFF0000' },
  };
   sheet.getCell('B30').fill = red;
   })
 

Вот результат попытки заливки ячейки H1


Пробуйте так:
const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Лист1');
const fillRed = {
  type: 'pattern',
  pattern: 'solid',
  fgColor: { argb: 'FFFF0000' },
};
sheet.getCell('B30').style = {
  ...(sheet.getCell('B30').style || {}),
  fill: fillRed
};

Github issue.

Большое спасибо за ответ, и за правки самого вопроса!
